# Pre-fill a keyword search filter on Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to load a page with a pre-filled value in an input field. The page and value do load, although it doesn't trigger anything in the filtered results until I enter something on the keyboard. Is there a way around this? I'd like it to just load the filtered results once the page loads.

I'm new to Angular JS, but appreciate any sort of help or push in the right direction.

I have tried:

`ng-init="search.keywords='initial'"` on the input tag and that doesn't seem to cause any filtering at happen.

`$scope.search = { keywords: 'initial' };` also loads the initial value, but doesn't trigger any filtering.

```
<input type="text" id="search-keywords" ng-model="search.keywords"
       class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword search">
```

```
$scope.$watch("search", function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal) {
        $scope.doFilter(newVal);
    }
}, true);


$scope.doFilter = function (search) {

    $scope.filtering = true;

    $scope.filteredCourses = $scope.filterExactMatchExceptNull($scope.courses, "inst", search.inst);

    $scope.filteredCourses = $scope.filterExactMatchExceptNull($scope.filteredCourses, "fos", search.fos);

    $scope.filteredCourses = $scope.filterCutoff($scope.filteredCourses, search.min, search.max);

    $scope.filteredCourses = $filter("filter")($scope.filteredCourses, {
        code: search.code,
        name: search.name,
        poa: search.poa
    });

    $scope.filteredCourses = $scope.filterByKeywords($scope.filteredCourses, search.keywords);

    $scope.limit = 15;

    if ($scope.limit >= $scope.filteredCourses.length) {
        $scope.limit = $scope.filteredCourses.length;
    }

    $scope.filtering = false;
};

$scope.filterByKeywords = function (courses, keywords) {
    if (!keywords || keywords == "") {
         return courses.filter(function (course) {
            return true;
        });
    } 

    var keywordArr = keywords.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/\W+/g, " ").replace(/\s\s+/g, " ").split(",");

         return courses.filter(function (course) {
             var matched = false;
             for (var i = 0, length = keywordArr.length; i < length; i++) {
                    if (course.keywords && course.keywords.indexOf(keywordArr[i]) > -1) {
                        matched = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return matched;
            });
        };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try by calling doFilter function as ng-init="doFilter({ keywords: 'initial' })"

Comment: I've just tried that, but it doesn't seem to load anything in the input field/search results at all - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

$watch function is used to detect any change in the inputfield after it is loaded into DOM.

So, to work it for the first time you may do:

Either use ng-init on the element to fire filter method on DOM load.

```
ng-init="doFilter(search)"
```

Or

Call filter function one time at controller level itself before actual watch starts.

```
$scope.search = { keywords: 'initial' }; 
$svope.doFilter($scope.search);
```

Comment: @JT__ Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the method which should be executed on initialization of the page in the ng-init directive:

```
ng-init="doFilter({keywords: 'initial'})"
```